# Javascript new function-object vs function-instantiation

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I have created a deck of cards that contains an array of 52 card objects. Each card inherits properties and methods defined in cardObject() function. However, I am confused with how to create new deck and access its properties and methods.

```js
// Defining properties and methods for every single card object created by PackOfCards function
function cardObject(cardNum, cardSuit) {
  this.cardNum = cardNum;
  this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
}
cardObject.prototype.getCardValue = function() {
  if (this.cardNum === "jack" || this.cardNum === "queen" || this.cardNum === "king") {
    return 10;
  } else if (this.cardNum === "ace") {
    return 11;
  } else {
    return this.cardNum;
  }
}
cardObject.prototype.getCardSuit = function() {
    return this.cardSuit;
  }

// Creating a deck of shuffled card where every card inherits properties and methods defined in cardObject function
function PackOfCards() {
  var unshuffledDeck = [],
    shuffledDeck = [];
  var listCardNum = ["ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "jack", "queen", "king"];
  var listCardSuits = ["clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"];
  for (var i = 0; i < listCardNum.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < listCardSuits.length; j++) {
      unshuffledDeck.push(new cardObject(listCardNum[i], listCardSuits[j])); //generating 52 new card objects
    }
  }
  var lengthCounter = unshuffledDeck.length;
  while (lengthCounter > 0) { // shuffling the 52 unshuffled cards randomly
    var tempPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * lengthCounter);
    shuffledDeck.push(unshuffledDeck.splice(tempPosition, 1));
    lengthCounter--
  }
  return shuffledDeck;
}

var newDeckObj = new PackOfCards;  // I've considered PackOfCards as constructer function here
var newDeckInstance = PackOfCards();  // I've created a variable that stores a new instance of PackOfCards() function that returns an array
console.log(newDeckObj[5].getCardValue);
console.log(newDeckObj[5].getCardValue);
```

Here I am unable to find the real true core difference between newDeckObj and newDeckInstance.

**Both contain an array of 52 objects BUT I get undefined trying to access its properties. I suppose both variables are some copy of PackOfCards() function but take different approach (one considers it a constructer which other just a function that returns an array) which I am unable to comprehend fully.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returned an object from your `PackOfCards` constructor, so it’s no longer a constructor. Using it with or without `new` makes no difference; it should just be a normal function.

The reason `undefined` is being logged is because splice returns an array of removed items, not just one (even if you only spliced one item out).

```
shuffledDeck.push(unshuffledDeck.splice(tempPosition, 1)[0]);
```

Moving the process of shuffling into another function and doing it in-place would be a good idea, though; it lets you test the shuffling part by itself.

```
function shuffle(collection) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length - 1; i++) {
        var swap = i + (Math.random() * (collection.length - i) | 0);
        var t = collection[i];
        collection[i] = collection[swap];
        collection[swap] = t;
    }
}
```

and

```
function getPackOfCards() {
  var deck = [];
  var listCardNum = ["ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "jack", "queen", "king"];
  var listCardSuits = ["clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"];
  for (var i = 0; i < listCardNum.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < listCardSuits.length; j++) {
      deck.push(new cardObject(listCardNum[i], listCardSuits[j])); //generating 52 new card objects
    }
  }

  return deck;
}

var deck = getPackOfCards();
shuffle(deck);
```

Comment: thanks ryan. so you mean that if i don't return anything from PackOfCards(), it will act as a constructer ? however the function has no public methods or properties so how will those be available to new objects without returning anything? will var deck = **new** PackOfCards();  still work?

Comment: @Jamie: If you want a function that returns an array, you can just do that. Not everything has to be a constructor.

Comment: so how will var deck = **new** getPackOfCard; work if i don't return the inner private array. any difference furthur down the line if i just do your way vs using **new**? thanks ;)

Comment: @Jamie There is no "inner private array". `getPackOfCards()` simply returns an array of cardObjects. This is not object oriented but it works. It may be harder to implement other feature later if you want to do like a game but not impossible.

Comment: @Jamie: You don’t use `new` unless you have a constructor. `getPackOfCards` is just a normal function and you’d do `var deck = getPackOfCards();`. If you want to make it a constructor `PackOfCards`, you can set `this.cards = deck;` or something.

Comment: @PierreC. actually i'm trying to create blackjack but i was unsure if not creating new PackOfCards instance using **new** keyword would prevent me from accessing the card methods and properties; as the way Ryan created new deck was by copying the value of the function(the returned array) into the variable. so i was bit careful there ;)